# Logic not working in filtering a list of values based on a threshold in R

Tags: r

I have a very simple issue I don't know how to solve.

I have the following list of very small values before conversion:

```
                  [,1]
V8530 0.00000009686643
V6196 0.00297853602192
V714  0.99999999760977
V9461 0.00003742696819
V9518 0.00141335323766
V9511 0.00047082401517
V9651 0.00011655255640
V6358 0.00000056338519
V5930 0.00000155667916
```

If the value > 0.09 then I want to convert it to 0.  If the value is less than 0.09 I want to substitute the value for 1.

**Logic for conversion**

```
  predicted_train_0_1[predicted_train_0_1 < 0.09] <- 1
  predicted_train_0_1[predicted_train_0_1 > 0.09] <- 0
```

These are my values after the conversion:

```
  [,1]
V8530    0
V6196    0
V714     0
V9461    0
V9518    0
V9511    0
V9651    0
V6358    0
V5930    0
```

I might be in need of sleeping or something else, but I can't figure out why!? The logic seems too simple to be wrong IMHO.

Any help is more than welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: All of the initial values but one are less than 0.09. So your first line of code converts them all to 1. Now all of the values are more than 0.09. So your second line of code converts all values to 0.

Comment: I tried to move them as I thought of that same cause, same thing but results to all values converted to 1.

Comment: Why not just `predicted_train_0_1[, 1] <- ifelse(predicted_train_0_1[, 1] < 0.09, 1, 0)`?

Comment: Or for that matter just `predicted_train_0_1 < 0.09` or `as.numeric(predicted_train_0_1 < 0.09)` if you're absolutely needing the 0's and 1's. Also what about cases that `== 0.09` ?

Comment: Yes, this is a good example of why if you want to use a logical index to assign new values, you need to save the logical index first: `index <- x < 0.09`, then `x[index] <- val1`, `x[! index] <- val2`

Comment: Don't fret the downvotes. Just about everyone will make this mistake (mutate the input and be confused about the output as a result). Probably more than once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common source of bugs. When you use a logical test on an object that you mutate, you have to remember that the result of your test will change.  There are a variety of solutions here, but the general idea is to store the result of the test in another object, before the input to the test is mutated.

The most basic solution:

```
index <- x < 0.09
x[index] <- 1
x[! index] <- 0
x
# [1] 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

`ifelse` does this behind the scenes, just with more error checking.

As @thelatemail points out, since you happen to be converting `TRUE` values in `index` to `1`, and `FALSE` values to `0`, in this case, you may be better served by just using `index`.

Data:

```
x <- c(0.00000009686643,
       0.00297853602192, 
       0.99999999760977, 
       0.00003742696819, 
       0.00141335323766,
       0.00047082401517,
       0.00011655255640,
       0.00000056338519,
       0.00000155667916)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first logic *`predicted_train_0_1[predicted_train_0_1 < 0.09] <- 1`* returned a vector of 1 and values which are > 0.09. Therefore, the second logic would return a list of all 0.

My solution is using the `dplyr` library:

```
library("dplyr")

x <- x %>% mutate(
  predicted_train = if_else(val > 0.9, 0, 1)
)
```

Here is the `x`:

```
x <- data.frame(val=c(0.00000009686643,
                  0.00297853602192, 
                  0.99999999760977, 
                  0.00003742696819, 
                  0.00141335323766,
                  0.00047082401517,
                  0.00011655255640))
```