# Boolean condition for list in R is not re-assigning original value to the correct value

Tags: r

This might be either a bug in my logic or a 'R way' of doing things that I'm not familiar with... I looked around but couldn't find any specific guidance.

I have 300 values in a list ranging from 0.4 up to 1 inclusive.

If a value is greater than or equal to 0.100000000 then I want to convert that value to 0. If the **value is not** greater than or equal to 0.100000 then the value should be 1.

This is the following logic given as a suggested answer in this post([Logic not working in filtering a list of values based on a threshold in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621928/logic-not-working-in-filtering-a-list-of-values-based-on-a-threshold-in-r/49628985#49628985)).

> This question is not a duplicate since the suggestion offered in that
>   post did not solve my issue and I have a different issue now where
>   only decimal numbers are not converted.

```
  index <- predicted_train >= 0.100000000
  predicted_train_0_1 <- predicted_train
  predicted_train_0_1[index] <- 0      
  predicted_train_0_1[!index] <- 1
```

It works *perfect* if the value in the predicted_train is 1, but is working entirely wrong if the value is a decimal (0.444 or 0.99999).  This is part of a prediction model. Of course, my prediction fails if the value in the original list is a decimal number and not an integer.

This is the dput output:

```
structure(c(0.00000000000887978249471495, 0.000000000102099666845067, 
0.999999999999994, 0.999999999994037, 0.999999999999902, 0.000000000456186801047934, 
0.000000276161153341468, 0.000000000152031909524259, 0.999999999999994, 
0.00341047330505499, 1, 0.0000179771008441045, 1, 0.999999999999999, 
1, 0.0000000510218964957691, 0.103743763293409, 1, 0.999999999846489, 
0.0000000000464043846752508, 0.000220612854089335, 0.0000000840458932539115, 
0.000111013075286084, 0.0000000000210686963713955, 0.000000000148986761281177, 
0.000000000746016702213319, 0.000201142836555311, 0.000000155811495478402, 
0.000000242817287729542, 0.000166576680354779, 0.99999999999998, 
0.000000000167007066190115, 0.00000000133793400573132, 0.000000000195006957555248, 
0.000202587575150869, 0.00000000000713476489269155, 0.00000000650740716038626, 
0.999999999958627, 0.999999972669627, 1, 0.00000000275149563085147, 
0.000146264551870513, 0.00000034266694046288, 0.000000012132408191839, 
1, 0.999999999905262, 0.9999999140199, 1, 1, 1, 0.999999999955009, 
1, 1, 0.00000140021466033136, 0.999999969966525, 0.999999997768666, 
0.0000000000824228162780307, 0.000000000211840087957173, 1, 1, 
0.999999999999988, 1)
```

**Approaches I tried**

I tried to remove the condition equals to in for the index variable.  I also tried it outside my main logic to isolate the problem.

Any help is more than welcome.

Comment: What's wrong with `ifelse(x >= 0.1, 0, 1)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logic not working in filtering a list of values based on a threshold in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621928/logic-not-working-in-filtering-a-list-of-values-based-on-a-threshold-in-r)

Comment: What's the problem? It works fine - take a look at `cbind(round(predicted_train,3), predicted_train_0_1, index)` and you can see it worked exactly as coded.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe ifelse?

```
my.df$newvalue <- ifelse(my.df$oldvalue>=.1,0,1)
```

overwriting oldvalue if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

We can just do to convert logical vector to binary

```
my.df$newvalue <- as.integer(my.df$oldvalue < .1)
```